# How do I check if a product has stock in any of it's variants?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Basically, I'm trying to show "Out of stock" and disable a button for when none of the variants have stock, and unlimited stock is unchecked.

I've tried this, which isn't working:

```
{% if product.variants.stock <= 0 and product.variants.unlimitedStock == false %}
    {{ "Out of stock"|t }}
{% else %}
    {{ "Add to cart"|t }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed do this with the following:

```
{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants({
    product: product,
    hasStock: true
}) %}

{% if variants|length <= 0 %}
  Sold out
{% else %}
  Add to basket
{% endif %}
```

The `hasStock` criteria takes `unlimitedStock` into consideration.

```
if (isset($criteria->hasStock) && $criteria->hasStock === true)
{
  $hasStockCondition = ['or', '(variants.stock > 0 AND variants.unlimitedStock != 1)', 'variants.unlimitedStock = 1'];
  $query->andWhere($hasStockCondition);
}
```

Comment: Great! I had previously tried {% set variants = craft.commerce.products({hasVariants {hasStock: true )} %}... Cheers!

Comment: According to https://craftcommerce.com/support/hiding-out-of-stock-products the query in your comment should work. I'm also having trouble with getting any results from this.

Comment: Should be `hasVariant` not `hasVariants`

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it's preferred by anyone else, here's a more compact and performant version of pretty much the same technique as Luke's answer:

`{% set inStock = product.variants|filter(v => v.hasStock())|length %}`

Less readable? Perhaps, but this way also saved me 14 queries compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: love your solution – great :-)