# Craft Commerce hasStock not working?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stock, products

I'm trying to query for certain products but only ones that have stock (the products just have defaultVariants):

```
{% set earliestDate = now | date_modify('- 1 days') %} 
{% set latestDate = now | date_modify('+ 10 days') %}
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
    hasVariants: {
        hasStock: true
    },
    type: 'class',
    date: 'and, > ' ~ earliestDate ~ ', < ' ~ latestDate,
    order: 'date',
    limit: 5
}) %}
```

The above returns 5 products, all of which happen to have no stock left as identified by them not showing when I use:

```
{% if product.defaultVariant.stock > 0 %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endif %}
```

I'm currently getting products to show by setting the limit to 25 and then it only shows 1 product in stock. Meaning the query is returning 25 products, of which 24 have no stock so shouldn't be returned.

Running Craft Commerce 1.2.1337 so am up-to-date.

Could be related to: [Commerce products returning different results on page load](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18663/commerce-products-returning-different-results-on-page-load)

Someone else mentioning it in comment to answer of this: [How do I check if a product has stock in any of it's variants?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17160/how-do-i-check-if-a-product-has-stock-in-any-of-its-variants/17168#17168)

Comment: Clive, looking at both of your SO questions, what is the `date` param in your query? did you mean `postDate` ?

Comment: Hi. No, `date` is a custom field.

Comment: Please send an email to support@craftcommerce.com, and include a copy of your DB backup. Also include your query twig code, and the expected product IDs that should show up. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your product element criteria is using a condition param: `hasVariants`, but it should be `hasVariant` as per the docs: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-products#hasvariant

That correctly only returns products (where a variant that belongs to that product) is in stock.

Comment: My bad. Sorry for wasting time on this. Now on to the random results I get from using this correct param: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18663/commerce-products-returning-different-results-on-page-load

Comment: That secondary issue was fixed in Commerce 1.2.1334